# List vertically all the order numbers ending in "TWC"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets with several sheets. I have it set up to where orders auto populate three of these sheets when entered into the *Order info* page.

I need to set up a function where only order numbers with a certain suffix (e.g. `WVCHA1234-TWC`) also auto populate another sheet within the same spreadsheet.  I don't need all orders in this sheet, just ones ending in `TWC`.

Is there a formula I can use for this?

Comment: What does this have to do with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FILTER` command.

If the order numbers are in sheet 3 column C, and you want the specific orders in sheet 4, use the formula

```
=FILTER(Sheet3!C:C, RIGHT(Sheet3!C:C, 3) = "TWC")
```

To list vertically all the order numbers ending in "TWC".
If you want not just the order number, but the entire row from Sheet 3, use

```
=FILTER(Sheet3!A:Z, RIGHT(Sheet3!C:C, 3) = "TWC")
```